# Doesn't Pooling in a Convolutional Neural Network lose precision in feature detection?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Like the title asks, in a CNN architecture from my understanding, we pool feature maps (returned by some convlayer). Upon obtaining the new response map by calculating max values from windows of the previous feature map, do we not lose precision in detecting the filter/feature in question?

Since we have just dropped a bunch of data.

I can understand the convlayer part, where we calculate the feature map using dot product...

But I'm just curious if we lose precision from the pooling operation?
Is there any purpose to the pooling operation besides making the Neural network more efficient?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pooling has a few benefits. As you note, there is a reduction in the number of features after pooling. This is not only useful from a computational perspective but also as a means to prevent overfitting. Reducing the feature space allows you to maintain a favorable sample to feature ratio. Another benefit of pooling is that it increases the receptive field of features. This is to say that after pooling the resulting feature is looking at a larger area of the prior layer. This can be handy for handling small image transformations.

For example (this is a bit contrived and not quite how it works), lets say that  you have convolutions that activate in layer 2 on a nose, face, and eyes and in layer three you have a convolution that activates on a pattern of those features to find faces. Different people have different eye spacing, eye to mouth position etc. Let's supposed you max pool over layer 2 on some window, you can be robust to those changes and the layer 3 filter will be able to activate.